# NameError: name 'select_pour_point' is not defined

Tags: python-2.7, arcgis, arcpy

I am receiving this error when trying to setup variables for each pour point.  It is a

cur_point = select_pour_point(POUR_POINTS, NAME_FIELD, name)

NameError: name 'select_pour_point' is not defined

HELP!

```
import shedtools as st

# Directories
SCRATCH = "C:\\SCRATCH"
OUT_FOLDER = "C:\\WATERSHEDS" 

# inputs
POUR_POINTS = "C:\\Hawaii_DEM\\Hawaii.shp"
FLOW_DIRECTION = "C:\\Hawaii_DEM\\hawaii_flwdir" 
STATS_RASTER = "C:\\HawaiiRFGrids_mm\\RF_MM_BI_Ann"                    
RASTER_NAME = "stats"
NAME_FIELD = "Id" 
STATISTICS = "MEAN"

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(POUR_POINTS, NAME_FIELD) as cursor:
    for point in cursor:
        name = str(point[0])
        print "Working on pour point %s" % (name)
        cur_point = select_pour_point(POUR_POINTS, NAME_FIELD, name) 
        shed_raster = make_watershed_raster(FLOW_DIRECTION, cur_point, name, SCRATCH)
```

Error I am receiving is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\\exercise_5.py", line 30, in <module>
    cur_point = select_pour_point(POUR_POINTS, NAME_FIELD, name)
NameError: name 'select_pour_point' is not defined
```

Line 30 is:

```
cur_point = select_pour_point(POUR_POINTS, NAME_FIELD, name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You import your shedtools.py script using `import shedtools as st`. Therefore, you need to prefix `select_pour_point` and `make_watershed_polygon` with `st.`:

- e.g. `st.select_pour_point(...)`

Not related to your error *BUT* open your `arcpy.da.SearchCursor` using `with` to make sure it is closed again after using.

```py
import shedtools as st

# ...

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(POUR_POINTS, NAME_FIELD) as cursor:
    for point in cursor:
        name = str(point[0])
        print "Working on pour point %s" % (name)
        cur_point = st.select_pour_point(POUR_POINTS, NAME_FIELD, name) 
        shed_raster = st.make_watershed_raster( \
                  FLOW_DIRECTION, cur_point, name, SCRATCH)
```

---

Alternatively, instead of prefixing your functions with `st.`, you could also import your functions using:

- `from shedtools import select_pour_point, make_watershed_raster`

If you do so, no prefixing is necessary:

```py
from shedtools import select_pour_point, make_watershed_raster

# ...

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(POUR_POINTS, NAME_FIELD) as cursor:
    for point in cursor:
        name = str(point[0])
        print "Working on pour point %s" % (name)
        cur_point = select_pour_point(POUR_POINTS, NAME_FIELD, name) 
        shed_raster = make_watershed_raster(FLOW_DIRECTION, cur_point, name, SCRATCH)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but I still get the same error:


`Working on pour point 0

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\.................", line 30, in <module>
    cur_point = select_pour_point(POUR_POINTS, NAME_FIELD, name)
NameError: name 'select_pour_point' is not defined`

Comment: Unless your add your new code in the question, I can't help. I assume you have 2 files (as indicated in your code example with a comment) and you use `from shedtools import select_pour_point, make_watershed_raster` as suggested now since you are not prefixing.

Comment: You import `shedtools` with `import shedtools as st`, therefore line 30 should be `st.select_pour_point(POUR_POINTS, NAME_FIELD, name)` and line 31 `st.make_watershed_raster(FLOW_DIRECTION, cur_point, name, SCRATCH)`. See my first example.

Comment: Now I get this, I posted it above

Comment: Please read the error message: `TypeError: select_pour_point() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)`. That means `st.select_pour_point` requires 4 arguments. Check your `shedtools.py`.